# Check if Metamask was just installed after asking the user to do so

Tags: metamask, dapp-development, browsers, user-experience

In an effort to make my dApp more user-friendly, especially for onboarding, I'm trying to guide new users into installing Metamask.

If no web3 provider is present, I show the user a "Create your wallet" button. When they click on it, they are headed to Metamask.io in a new tab.

The trouble arises when they install Metamask and go back to my dApp. There doesn't seem to be a way of detecting if a web3 provider is installed without reloading. I can't just programmatically reload the whole page, and asking my disengaged potential user to reload feels like very bad UX.

I created the following [code snippet](https://github.com/e18r/web3test) taken from [Metamask's documentation](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-provider-api) to illustrate this behaviour.

```
<html>
<body>
  <script language="javascript">
  function checkProvider () {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
      console.log('you already have a web3 provider');
    } else {
      console.log('please install Metamask');
    }
  }
  var interval = setInterval(checkProvider, 1000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically it checks every second if you have a web3 provider. Since it can't run without a webserver, I [put it online](https://web3test.netlify.app) so you can quickly test it.

If I don't have Metamask installed, I get the expected message:

[image: please install metamask]

But after I install it and go back to this page, the same message keeps appearing:

[image: metamask isn't detected without a refresh]

Only after a refresh does my snippet detect metamask:

[image: metamask is detected after a refresh]

I can't be the only one facing onboarding issues with web3 providers. What workarounds have you thought of?

Comment: Same problem here. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to programmatically refresh the page to get web3 injected by metamask. You can write a recurisve function which will not run indefinetly and will refresh if metamask was not installed and installed later:

```
function checkWeb3ProviderRecursively(firstCall = true) {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
        console.log("web3 provide detected")
        // reload the page
        if(!firstCall) document.location.reload()
    } else {
        console.log("Please install metamask")
        // add a delay here as you want
        checkWeb3ProviderRecursively(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to put the reload statement in the `else` block? If you already detected the web3 provider, you don't need to refresh, whereas if you haven't detected it you need to refresh in order to re-check

Comment: I am using react and I found that when the user finishes installing MetaMask, the `window` object won't be updated which means this function will still find that `window.ethereum` is `undefined` until it gets reloaded. Recurring doesn't help in React.

Answer (score 0):

ethereum.on('connect', (connectInfo) => {
console.log("connected to wallet");
console.log(connectInfo);
});

OR

https://docs.metamask.io/guide/onboarding-library.html#getting-started